# Prime number calculator. Are these both correct?

Tags: c, algorithm, primes

Been trying to write program for displaying prime numbers and just wanted to know if there is much difference between the following two algorithms.

**1,**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXNUMB 100000

int main(void){
   int flag;
   long i,j=MAXNUMB;
   printf ("The Prime Numbers up to %ld are:\n       2\n", j);
   for(i=3 ; i<=MAXNUMB; i = i+2){
       j = 3;           //only difference is in this line
       flag = 0;
       while((j*j <= i) && flag == 0){
            if(i%j == 0){
                flag = 1;
            }
            j++;
      }
      if (flag == 0){
         printf("%8ld\n",i);
      }
  }
}
```

**2,**

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #define MAXNUMB 100000

  int main(void){
     int flag;
     long i,j=MAXNUMB;
     printf ("The Prime Numbers up to %ld are:\n       2\n", j);
     for(i=3 ; i<=MAXNUMB; i = i+2){
        j = 2;       //again this is the only different line
        flag = 0;
        while((j*j <= i) && flag == 0){
             if(i%j == 0){
                flag = 1;
            }
            j++;
    }
    if (flag == 0){
        printf("%8ld\n",i);
    }
 }
}
```

It seems to me that both work but im not sure, maybe someone can shed some light.

Also, any general tips for someone starting to code, that apply for all programmers?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you run it twice with the different lines?

Comment: It depends on your definition of "much".

Comment: @Michael Walz   What i meant to say is: Is there any difference at all? In the output or efficiency?

Comment: To me it seems like they have the same output but i cant check every number

Comment: @riegour of course you can, that's why we have computers :)

Comment: Please correct the block indentation of your code. You can use a literal (such as `MAXNUMB`) in many places of a `C` source code: there is no reason to set `j` to it. Advice: [Document code internally](http://www.doxygen.org/). Use a system for trace&debug output. With imperative code, watch process state change following the instructions - using a debugger, if not pen and paper. With a problem new to you, give it a try, and have a look at what and how others have done, by turns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both have the same output because you're skipping over even numbers with `i = i + 2` and starting the loop with `i = 3`. So the `i % j == 0` condition will never be true when `j = 2`.

> To me it seems like they have the same output but i cant check every number

Wrap your approaches into separate functions, return the results in an array and then compare both arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can very quickly see the time it takes for these to complete with the built in `time` function for GNU/Linux or Cygwin. Using the G++ compiler, it takes around `0.109s` to run the first snippet and around `0.141s` to run the second one. So I guess it depends on what your definition of "more efficient" is. Note: I did not check for the accuracy of the results, just running the programs as they are.

As for general programming tips, you have access to boundless information on the internet, just search up programming tips. One could write an entire book on "tips" for a beginning programmer. [Here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/the-10-most-common-beginner-programming-mistak.html) is a good example.